# prevent re-render of every marker when a state has changed

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-maps

I'm currently working on a hobby project that involves implementing a map system with custom markers. The challenge I'm encountering is that every marker on the map undergoes a re-render, even when the changed state isn't utilized by the map or markers themselves.

As a test, I've written the following code:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState(false);

const handleMapPress = () => {
  setTest(!test);
}
```

The handleMapPress function is triggered when the onPress event occurs on the MapView. Despite the fact that test is not used anywhere else in the component, all of the markers undergo a re-render, resulting in flickering on my display.

I have tried React.memo but the markers still re-render.

I'm seeking advice on how to address this issue.

Edit: added current code for MapMarker

```js
      const MapMarker = ({ coordinate, isActive, onPress }) => {
        return (
          <Marker coordinate={coordinate}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
              <Image
                source={
                  isActive
                    ? require('assets/icons8-map-marker2-64.png')
                    : require('assets/icons8-map-marker-64.png')
                }
                style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Marker>
        );
      };

      return (
        <View
          style={[
            mapStyles.container,
            {
              flexDirection: 'column'
            },
          ]}>
          {(
          <MapView 
            initialRegion={initialRegion} 
            style={[styles.container]} 
            onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange} 
            onPress={handleMapPress}>
              {data.map((item, index) => (
                <MapMarker
                  isActive={index === activeMarker}
                  onPress={() => handleMarkerPress(index, item)}
                  value={item}
                  key={index}
                  coordinate={{
                    latitude: item.latitude,
                    longitude: item.longitude,
                  }}
                />
              ))}
          </MapView>
          )}
        </View>
      );
```

Comment: Provide more context. Post your code or an minimal sample.

Comment: @MichaelBahl added my current code for rendering custom marker

Comment: Does the flickering occur in iOS and android ?
How many Markers are placed?

Comment: At this moment I am testing with 5 markers a bit apart from each other. I am testing on IOS

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the behavior you described https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/mapview-marker

Comment: Yea I have made a snack myself with my current code: https://snack.expo.dev/@speedt4/map-marker?platform=ios I can't reproduce the problem myself either in the simulator.
Here is a gif of what I see on my mobile screen: https://jmp.sh/s/wEEEUtYWLOOK4oMuc4Hu

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing with markers re-rendering when there's a state change that doesn't affect them is likely due to the fact that your MapMarker component is not being memorized correctly. `React.memo` is a useful tool to prevent unnecessary re-renders.

```js
  const MapMarker = React.memo(
    ({ coordinate, isActive, onPress }) => {
      return (
        <Marker coordinate={coordinate}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
            <Image
              source={
                isActive
                  ? require('assets/icons8-map-marker2-64.png')
                  : require('assets/icons8-map-marker-64.png')
              }
              style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Marker>
      );
    },
    (prevProps, nextProps) => {
      // Only re-render when isActive changes
      return prevProps.isActive === nextProps.isActive;
    }
  );
```

re-render only when the `isActive` property changes.

Comment: No this does not work, I have tried it couple days ago. Thanks for your example!

Comment: Can you make a expo project ? (reproduce the error)

Comment: Let me search how its done

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@speedt4/map-marker?platform=ios But the problem is not reproduced in the simulator like on my phone screen

Comment: Here is a gif of what I see on my mobile screen: https://jmp.sh/s/wEEEUtYWLOOK4oMuc4Hu

Comment: Dont use `TouchableOpacity`. `Marker` from `react-native-maps` already have an onPress function. And also the Image property [docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md)